# Does IBM have 64-bit JVM for Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650?

Tags: java, sdk, jvm

I checked the page http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/download.html and see "64-bit AMD/Opteron/EM64T".

Tried to install it and got "The installer cannot run on your configuration"!

Answer (score 0):

Was there a stack trace or any message after the one you list? 
.
Have you checked for /etc/mailcap & /etc/mime.types - if you don't have them you'll need to install the mailcap package before trying the install and then 
Create dummy files /etc/mailcap and /etc/mime.types